# How to learn database management systems?

Tags: self-learning, databases, sql

database

- navathe/elmasri
- connally begg
- date
- korth
- gehrke/ramakrishnan
- Database Design for Mere Mortals: A Hands-On Guide to Relational Database Design 2nd Edition
- database systems peter rob, coronel
- Celko

These are the books I'm planning to purchase to learn database. (Books are really cheap in Nepal and I'm employed as Linuxadmin).

I am not a fan of books though. I like video courses.

I already have hands on sql experience. But I feel learning sql is the tip of iceberg of database knowledge pool.

But the only decent course that I could find is this CMU course.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uikbtpVZS2s&list=PLSE8ODhjZXjaKScG3l0nuOiDTTqpfnWFf

But I prefer reading 10 different books for 1 concept rather than watching 1 2 hrs video.

Do you guys have any idea on other resources that I can purchase to learn database? My goal is database fundamentals, I already know sql to some extent.

http://ioesyllabus.blogspot.com/2015/05/database-management-systems-syllabus.html

This is the syllabus I want to follow.

Comment: "How to learn database management systems? " - The best way to learn anything is by first understand it, practice it, and apply it. There is no any magics involved here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the book "Database System Concepts"-  Henry F. Korth, S. Sudarshan, Abraham Silberschatz. I hope it will help you to build the database concepts and the book simply describes the concepts!